# How to mount a common sqlite database file for python flask application running on three node docker-swarm cluster?

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, flask-sqlalchemy, docker-swarm

I have a python flask REST application which when deployed creates a .db sqlite database file. This application is now deployed on three node docker swarm cluster. I use a swarm-stack file to deploy the container on those nodes. My problem is now each container has its own .db file i.e. a separate database for each instance of the application. I want a common mount point for this db file so that each service should access a common database. How can I implement this? I am new to docker.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing files across entire nodes/machines isn't something Docker will directly solve for you, but you can take a look at Docker storage drivers in the context of [shared storage systems](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/#shared-storage-systems-and-the-storage-driver). This helps it integrate with solutions such as NFS, ZFS, etc.

However, you mentioned that you're using SQLite and Flask, using the SQLAlchemy driver. To save you a huge headache, rather than trying to share a filesystem across your three nodes, you should use a database server such as [MySQL](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql), [MariaDB](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb), or [PostgreSQL](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) (to name a few), all which work well with SQLAlchemy. That way, instead of trying to share the same SQLite file with all running instances of your Flask app (which will lock/degrade very often/quickly), you can have all of your Flask containers connect to the same database container.

This extra database can be easily run within a container and also managed by `docker-compose`. This way, only one node needs access to the filesystem to store data for the database.

Comment: Its not possible for me to switch to another database within a short time. I am not able to find concrete information on shared storage systems. Is there something like binding volume and files to multiple containers? Will that work? I am not sure on this.

Comment: Are you using multiple containers on multiple machines, or multiple containers on a single machine? The point of an ORM like SQLAlchemy is so you can switch between database types with relative ease. If you are using multiple machines then it's going to require a huge amount of effort to configure. Look into "distributed filesystems for cloud".

Comment: I am using 3 machines (1 leader, 2 worker nodes). So the docker image is present on the leader machine and the containers get deployed on all three machines.

Comment: That makes sense. SQLite is really, *really* not the way to go in this case. It locks during high load, and trying to set it up on a network-based filesystem will cause performance to degrade even faster than if it were running on a single machine (i.e. setting it up this way forgoes the benefits of setting up any replicas - you'd be better without them).